# Pandas count number of occurrence in past N days, meeting certain conditions

Tags: pandas

Supposed I have the following dataframe and that I want to count the number of occurrence "True" in the same Category for the past 14 days, how can I do this? For example, the following dataframe will produce a column with values : 0,1,1,0,2,0,1,0

```
Date         Category   has_egg
2017-01-01   Lunch      True
2017-01-02   Lunch      True 
2017-01-02   Lunch      False
2017-01-02   Dinner     True
2017-01-12   Lunch      False
2017-01-13   Breakfast  False  
2017-01-13   Dinner     False
2017-02-04   Lunch      True
```

I tried using group by but couldn't figure out the exact command

```
df.groupby("Category").has_egg.count_number_of_True(time_delta(-14d)) ?
```

Comment: Do you think `time_delta(-14d)` substract max date of group from each date and compare if less as 14 days ? For me it return `[True, True, True, False, True, False, False, False]`. How do you get your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get a pretty general solution by just combining `resample` & `rolling` with `groupby`.  (Note that the code below assumes your index is a proper python/pandas datetime.  If not, you'd need to first convert it with `pd.to_datetime`.)

```
df.groupby('Category').resample('d').sum().fillna(0).\
   groupby('Category').rolling(14,min_periods=1).sum()
```

The `resample` line just corrects for the fact that you could have more or less than one row per date/category.  Then you can use `rolling` in a very straightforward way.

Here's part of the output:

```
Lunch     Lunch     2017-01-01      1.0
                    2017-01-02      2.0
                    . . .

                    2017-01-14      2.0
                    2017-01-15      1.0
                    2017-01-16      0.0
```

Alternatively, for conciseness, here's what it looks like at a weekly level:

```
df.groupby('Category').resample('w').sum().fillna(0).\
   groupby('Category').rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum()

                                has_egg
Category  Category  Date               
Breakfast Breakfast 2017-01-15      0.0
Dinner    Dinner    2017-01-08      1.0
                    2017-01-15      1.0
Lunch     Lunch     2017-01-01      1.0
                    2017-01-08      2.0
                    2017-01-15      1.0
                    2017-01-22      0.0
                    2017-01-29      0.0
                    2017-02-05      1.0
```

I think this way ought to be quite fast, though not memory efficient since it expands your data to one row per each date/category combo.  If memory is a problem you'd want to look at some alternative approaches (which would probably be somewhat slower and less elegant, so I wouldn't worry about that unless your data is fairly large).

Also note:  I believe this code should also work fine if you have more than one True value for a unique date/category even though your sample data did not include that case.  You may want to edit the sample data for that possibility if it's important to you to be able to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see this as a possible solution however it produced a separate df which is slightly different than what the original question is asking for.

Comment: @JohnE I agree what I did is not efficient and this is  efficient way to do. +1 for this.

Comment: @open-source  Thanks!  Never hurts to have 2 good, but different answers. ;-)

Comment: @JohnE thanks for pointing out efficiency with some test! it's always good and helpful.  If you make changes and let the user know, may be he can switch to this as accepted answer (*I don't know how it works so I used may be*) that way it will help others with similar issue and large data in future.

Comment: @open-source  It's always up to the person who posted the question.  It's 100% fine the way the way it is now as far as I'm concerned but I appreciate the upvote.  Your answer is closer to what the poster wanted and I don't feel like re-doing my answer at this point anyway.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well this may be not efficient way, but something you could do is, iterate over each row and build a `mask` or other `dataframe` that meets the requirements, and count them to update to new `column`.

```
# converting to pandas datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
print(df)
```

Result `df` is:

```
         Date   Category has_egg
0  2017-01-01      Lunch    True
1  2017-01-02      Lunch    True
2  2017-01-02      Lunch   False
3  2017-01-02     Dinner    True
4  2017-01-12      Lunch   False
5  2017-01-13  Breakfast   False
6  2017-01-13     Dinner   False
7  2017-02-04      Lunch    True
```

Now, iterate through each row and look for the ones that meet all requirement and sum them:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    mask = (df.Category == row.Category) & (df.Date > (row.Date - pd.Timedelta(days=14))) & (df.Date < row.Date) & (df.has_egg == True)
    df.loc[index, 'values'] = sum(mask) # insert to the new column

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Date   Category has_egg  values
0  2017-01-01      Lunch    True     0.0
1  2017-01-02      Lunch    True     1.0
2  2017-01-02      Lunch   False     1.0
3  2017-01-02     Dinner    True     0.0
4  2017-01-12      Lunch   False     2.0
5  2017-01-13  Breakfast   False     0.0
6  2017-01-13     Dinner   False     1.0
7  2017-02-04      Lunch    True     0.0
```

Comment: I mark this as correct solution, as this produce the answer the original question is asking. I am not sure if there are better ways to to do this because this takes 80 core to run  over 3 minutes on a df of 3000 rows.

Comment: @ArMonk I'm not criticizing this answer because I think it's nicely coded (and I gave it +1), but doing a quick timing of my code on a laptop (quite a bit less than 80 cores) it timed at 16.1ms which is like a 10,000x or so speedup.  Which is not surprising because it's a comparison of vectorized code vs loops.

Comment: After all I did unticked this an accepted answers because it seems this piece of code cannot run on a larger data set, hence I cannot continue my analysis.